# Какой пароль по умолчанию в предустановленной Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, password

Так получилось, что я на днях потратил изрядно времени в поисках ответа на этот вопрос с предустановленным ubuntu сервером. Поэтому у меня уже есть на него ответ и я хочу им просто поделиться. Логин/пароль - ubuntu/ubuntu.

Comment: Ответ должен быть во ответе, а не в самом вопросе.

Comment: такая информация бесполезна: какие учётные записи создали при «предустановке», такие и будут, какие пароли при этом задали, такие и будут. обращайтесь в следующий раз к тому, кто вам «предустанавливал» систему.

Comment: Я бы задал вопрос по-другому: "как сбросить пароль на установленном линуксе?". Но меня скорее всего тут же ткнут в ранее отвеченные топики.